# How to find similar lines in two text files irrespective of the line number at which they occur

Tags: java

I am trying to open two text files and find similar lines in them.
My code is correctly reading all the lines from both the text files.
I have used nested `for` loops to compare `line1` of first text file with all lines of second text file and so on.
However, it is only detecting similar lines which have same line number,
(eg. line 1 of `txt1` is `cc cc cc` and line 1 of `txt2` is `cc cc cc`, then it correctly finds and prints it),
but it doesn't detect same lines on different line numbers in those files.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FeatureSelection500 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here

        File f1 = new File("E://implementation1/practise/ComUpdatusPS.exe.hex-04-ngrams-Freq.txt");
        File f2 = new File("E://implementation1/practise/top-300features.txt");

        Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(f1);

        Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(f2);

        int i = 1;
        List<String> txtFileOne = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<String> txtFileTwo = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (scan1.hasNext()) {
            txtFileOne.add(scan1.nextLine());
        }

        while (scan2.hasNext())

        {

            txtFileTwo.add(scan2.nextLine());
        }
     /*
    for(String ot : txtFileTwo )
    {
    for (String outPut : txtFileOne)

    {
       // if (txtFileTwo.contains(outPut))
        if(outPut.equals(ot))
        {

           System.out.print(i + " "); 

           System.out.println(outPut);
           i++;


        }

    }
    }
*/

        for (int j = 0; j < txtFileTwo.size(); j++) {

            String fsl = txtFileTwo.get(j);
            //  System.out.println(fileContentSingleLine);

            for (int z = 0; z < 600; z++)                                 // z < txtFileOne.size()
            {
                String s = txtFileOne.get(z);
                //  System.out.println(fsl+"\t \t"+ s);
                if (fsl.equals(s)) {
                    System.out.println(fsl + "\t \t" + s);
                    // my line

                    // System.out.println(fsl);
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: both the loops are working well yet I am not getting what goes wrong in if statement which detects similar text only on same line number and not the way I want it to be

Comment: Please fix your formatting. It's very difficult to understand as is.

Comment: It won't make a difference!

Comment: Continue - Causes the loop to skip the remainder of its body and immediately retest its condition prior to reiterating.

Comment: There are two `for` loops here and the inner for loop do not have any instructions after the `continue` statement. I know that it is not needed here but even it's present it won't make any difference.

Comment: I think he needs to specify which loop is being continued if he wants to keep it.

Comment: Seems very expensive, why not hash each line & return the lines with duplicate hashes?

Comment: bro i got thousands of lines in each file and like that I got thousands of files to be precise ( 4500 files each with 10000 lines) so no chnace of hashing. It started working fine and I dont think continue was the cause of problem.

Comment: Anway I am using this code to create dataset for my antivirus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made your code look nicer, you're welcome :)
Anyway, I don't understand that you get that bug. It runs through all of the list2 for every line in the list1...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FeatureSelection500 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    // TODO code application logic here

    File file1 = new File("E://implementation1/practise/ComUpdatusPS.exe.hex-04-ngrams-Freq.txt");
    File file2 = new File("E://implementation1/practise/top-300features.txt");

    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(file1);

    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(file2);

    List<String> txtFile1 = new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> txtFile2 = new ArrayList<String>();

    while (scan1.hasNext()) {
        txtFile1.add(scan1.nextLine());
    }

    while (scan2.hasNext()) {
        txtFile2.add(scan2.nextLine());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < txtFile2.size(); i++) {
        String lineI = txtFile2.get(i);
        //  System.out.println(fileContentSingleLine);
        for (int j = 0; j < txtFile1.size(); j++){ // z < txtFileOne.size(
            String lineJ = txtFile1.get(j);
            //  System.out.println(fsl+"\t \t"+ s);
            if (lineI.equals(lineJ)) {
                System.out.println(lineI + "\t \t" + lineJ);
                // my line

                // System.out.println(fsl);
            }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot orjan sunnerhagen, ya even I wasnt able to figure out the problem. However it worked correctly yesterday dont know how :P . M really curious to find out what was creating a problem for it earlier.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with your code. Even the block you commented is absolutely fine. Since, you are doing `equals()` you should make sure that you have same text (same case) in the two files for them to be able to satisfy the condition successfully.

```
for(String ot : txtFileTwo )
{
    for (String outPut : txtFileOne)
    {
        if(outPut.equals(ot)) /* Check Here */
        {
            /* Please note that here i will not give you line number,
               it will just tell you the number of matches in the two files */
            System.out.print(i + " "); 
            System.out.println(outPut);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: buddy thanks for your comment but your i here wont be a line number anyway that is not a concern so not a problem

Comment: If you want the line numbers then you'll have to change the two for loops to `for(int i = 0; i < ot.length; i++)` style.